# VisualVM profiler throws null pointer exception for empty main

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

**Edit:** The missing part was the binaries of VisualVM. I ve installed only ide extension part.

I've installed VisualVM to profile some java codes but its giving same error as soon as I run the application. Tried different codes, even with an empty "main", it gives same exception. What should I do do start profiling on windows-7 64 bit and Eclipse Luna? I need to profile which thread spends most time on creating objects and which objects needs most garbage collection time.

Here is some config information:

```
Eclipse luna + java 8 + visualvm 1.1.1

java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_25-b18
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=25.25-b02
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using VisualVM Eclipse launcher http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html ?

Comment: Yes I was, later I realized Ive installed just the profiler's ide extension, not the binary setup.